# When to use built-in Graph/GraphPlot vs. Combinatorica

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

What are the pros and cons of using built-in Graph/GraphPlot (and related) types vs. types in the Combinatorica package?

Comment: Use built-in whenever you can, because Combinatorica is deprecated. It actually gives you this warning when you load it, and can cause shadowing of some of the built-in functions, causing conflict.

Comment: Nice question. I'd like to see a summary of virtues and drawbacks of each.

Comment: Typically, I found it easier to work with labeling and styling vertices and edges with the *Combinatorica* graph objects. And unless I'm mistaken, there are still some operations upon graphs that are easier to do with *Combinatorica* than with the newer `System` graph objects. But as @R.M. indicates, it's better not to rely upon a deprecated package.

Comment: Also, in my view `ToCombinatoricaGraph` needs to be used with caution.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6230554/499167) on Stack Overflow

Comment: The **``Combinatorica` ``** package has been shipping with Mathematica for a long time, and contains a lot of functionality, including graph-related functions.  One difficulty with it is that the documentation is not included and [has to be bought separately](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0521806860).  This is one reason I'm not very familiar with this package.  **`GraphPlot`** is *only* for visualizing graphs, and was introduced in version 5 if I'm not mistaken.  It doesn't have any other functionality (there's some in `GraphUtilities`).

Comment: **`Graph`** is a  built-in type introduced in version 8. Since it's built-in, it can be quite efficient (at least in theory).  It is clearly meant to replace all Combinatorica-related functionality because some of it conflicts with Combinatorica and now there is a warning message when loading Combinatorica.  However, not all Combinatorica functions have a built-in equivalent (yet?) and there are still some bugs to be ironed out (I'm really hoping v9 will bring lots of improvement).  To sum up: if you don't have the Combinatorica book, use `Graph` (the future) and fall back to C'ca when needed.

Comment: Yet another thing: AFAIK Combinatorica has no support for graphs with unconnected vertices (I might be wrong).  `Graph` does.  `GraphPlot` can plot multigraphs, while `Graph` can't represent them.  `GraphPlot` produces very similar layouts to `Graph`, but it's not always equivalent, and I still use `GraphPlot` on occasion.  Some people (me included) don't like the Property API introduced with `Graph` as it's not functional, and you need to keep in mind that `Graph` is an atomic type that can only be accessed indirectly through this API. (It's not like other Mma expressions.)

Answer (score 5):

You should always use the built-in `Graph` unless there is a specific reason to use Combinatorica instead.

Valid reasons to use Combinatorica could be:

- Working with very old code, originally written for Combinatorica
- The need for an algorithm that is neither available as a built-in, nor in any supported package. (There are still a few of these, e.g. `ListGraphs`).  <sub>**Update:** The [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) package now provides replacements for many of such Combinatorica functions. As for `ListGraphs`, I suggest using the `geng` tool from [the Nauty suite](https://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/). It's output format, [Graph6](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Graph6.html), can be read directly by Mathematica.</sub>
- You are learning about graph theory and combinatorics from the [Combinatorica Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521121469)

Problems when using Combinatorica:

- Not supported anymore. There will be inconvenient conflicts with built-in symbols. [See here for how to make this less painful.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5574/12)  Minor compatibility problems with recent Mathematica versions could happen.
- The documentation is lacking.  The expectation is that you would buy the [Combinatorica Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521121469).
- Performance is not great.  All functions are implemented purely in Mathematica.  (On the upside: you can read the source code, and the algorithms/implementations are explained in the Combinatorica Book.)  Because of this is not suitable for "network science" type applications.  It is meant for (mathematical) graph theory.

---

Here's the guide on replacing Combinatorica with builtin functionality:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Combinatorica.html

The `` GraphUtilities` `` package contains the `ToCombinatoricaGraph` function which can convert a built-in [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) expression to a `` Combinatorica`Graph ``, in case you need some algorithms from Combinatorica.

---

A for `GraphPlot`, it is purely for visualization, and almost all of its functionality is already built into `Graph`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it also depends on your data. In my work, I do use the Laplacian for my research which can be, in principle, related to the adjacency matrix. In order to "visualize" my network I use the following:

```
GraphPlot[LaplacianMatrix]
```

Since I don't want to do an additional transformation `Laplacian -> Adjacency Matrix` (it takes time), I never use `Graph` as well as `` Combinatorica` `` for such stuff.

Comment: I wouldn't say that `GraphPlot` supports Laplacian matrices. Instead, it simply ignores signs, self-loops and multi-edges by default. You could do `SimpleGraph@AdjacencyGraph@Abs[lm]` instead, or define `laplacianGraph = SimpleGraph @* AdjacencyGraph @* Abs`.