# How to load a package without naming conflicts?

Tags: functions, packages, combinatorics, contexts

This question applies to any package, but I encountered this problem while working with graphs.
There are symbols in the `Combinatorica` package (such as `Graph`, `IncidenceMatrix`, `EdgeStyle`, and others) that have the same name as analogous symbols in `System`. If I execute `` Needs[Combinatorica`] ``, then I can access `` Combinatorica`Graph `` by the name `Graph`, but if I want to access `` System`Graph ``, I have to write `` System`Graph ``.

I want to use the `` Combinatorica` `` prefix to access all the symbols in `` Combinatorica` ``, and I want to access `` System` `` symbols without using a prefix. And I don't want to have the symbols `Graph`, `IncidenceMatrix`, and so on, in red in Mathematica because of the naming conflict.

Is there a way to use the `` Combinatorica` `` package without introducing naming conflicts?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Shadowing occurs only when there are two functions with the same name that are in `$ContextPath`. So right after you do `` <<Combinatorica` ``, do the following:

```
$ContextPath = Rest@$ContextPath;
```

What this does is that it removes `Combinatorica` (which is the package you just loaded). Now the only `Graph` function that's on the path is `` System`Graph `` and you can call it simply by the name, without the prefix. To access any functions from the package, use the prefix, as `` Combinatorica`Graph ``.

If `` Combinatorica` `` was loaded a while ago and you have loaded other packages in between, `Rest@...` is not going to be helpful. In that case, use:

```
$ContextPath = DeleteCases[$ContextPath, "Combinatorica`"];
```

Answer (score 42):

The answer of @R.M. already explains the essence of the problem. You can streamline the process of removing the `Combinatorica` from the `$ContextPath` by loading it via

```
Block[{$ContextPath},  Needs["Combinatorica`"]]
```

(or use `Get` intead of `Needs`, although `Needs` is a preferred way to load a package). In this way, you don't have to do anything afterwards, since, once the scope of `Block` is left, the `$ContextPath` automatically is reset to its previous value.

This is a generally useful trick to load packages without adding them to the `$ContextPath`. I found it quite useful on many occasions.

Comment: [Here's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23685/12) something that's good to be aware of (see under P.S.)  If using Combinatorica, there's a chance one might need to use the `ToCombinatoricaGraph` function as well.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use something like `` Graph=System`Graph; `` and use `Graph` which refers to `` System`Graph `` thereafter. You can use any other name such as `` g=System`Graph `` as well. The downside is that you have to do it for any function.

Edit:
This does the trick:

```
rep = StringReplace[#, "System`" -> ""] &;
Scan[
 Unprotect[#]; ToExpression[# <> "=System`" <> #]; Protect[#]; &,
 Intersection[
  rep /@ Names["Combinatorica`*"],
  rep /@ Names["System`*"]
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: You don't have to do the `rep /@ Names["Combinatorica\`*"]` part, you know...

Comment: ``Graph = System`Graph``  sounds like a very bad idea.  If `Graph` refers to ``Combinatorica`Graph``, doing this will break Combinatorica.  Contexts/namespaces in Mathematica don't work like in Python.