# Importing parts of Packages

Tags: packages, kernel, system

Some programming languages offer the possibility of importing a single function from a library, as in

```
from x import y
```

I'm looking to import only one function (`GraphCoordinates`) from the `GraphUtilities` package.

The following commands do not work:

```
<< GraphUtilities`GraphCoordinates

Needs["GraphUtilities`", "GraphCoordinates"]
```

The former gives an error, while the latter loads the entire `GraphUtilities` package.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A version of this question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912984/exposing-symbols-to-contextpath) on StackOverflow. You can look at the answers there for some options. To summarize, Mathematica currently does not natively support such a fine-grained encapsulation, which would certainly be a nice thing to have (IMO).

One simple thing you can do is to load the entire package via

```
Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["GraphUtilities`"]]
```

(see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5563/how-to-load-a-package-without-naming-conflicts/5574#5574) for an explanation), and then refer to your function by its long name:

```
GraphUtilities`GraphCoordinates
```

You can then go further and create an alias in your current context, if you don't want to type the long name:

```
GraphCoordinates = GraphUtilities`GraphCoordinates
```

Since the loaded package is not on the `$ContextPath`, this will not lead to shadowing. Note however that such aliases will work most of the time, but not always.

This workaround should work fine *if* you are ok to load the entire package and just don't want all its public functions to become public in your current context (`` "Global`" ``,or whatever it is). If you truly want to avoid even loading the entire package, you are (currently) out of luck.

Comment: Bleh! This is what I feared... Since I found nothing in the official documentation. Thanks for the hack!