# How to define a package without adding it to $ContextPath

Tags: packages

How can you introduce a package, so that it is listed in `$Packages`, without adding it to `$ContextPath`?

Note that this question is concerned with defining a package when evaluating code, e.g. through evaluating a cell, rather than loading a package from a file.

This is useful if you want to add capabilities without introducing new "bare" symbols in any way -- they live in their own context and must be referenced through an explicit context, unless the user adds that context back to the context path.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you cannot use the equivalent of ``Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["Combinatorica`"]]`` because the package is defined in a notebook, and it *must* be in multiple, separate input lines (therefore can't be wrapped)?  `BeginPackage` affects parsing, so it takes effect only starting with the next input.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5574/5) seems to work even if you were to define the package and not load it (basically what Szabolcs said)

Comment: @rm-rf Nope, that can't be used if you define the package in a cell.  The reason is that as soon as you wrap the definition in `Block`, it becomes a single input that is parsed *before* `BeginPackage` is evaluated and changes the context.  So while it may appear to work on first try, the package symbols will all be created in the Global context.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ah yes, you're right.

Comment: Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917550/why-doesnt-this-use-of-begin-work  BTW I upvoted this because when one starts to think of alternative solutions, it'll become clear that Joel's solution is not as trivial to figure out as it looks.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks. I came across this problem in the course of my work, and thought there are multiple ways to approach it. I was not able to whip off the right solution immediately either; I first tried wrapping the BeginPackage in a With, similar to the Block, and that made the package symbols get parsed into Global`. So I had to work at this a bit to arrive at my proposed answer.

Comment: Ironically, just a day later I discovered that in 9.0.1 the ``Predictions` `` context is added to the context path.  It seems like a bug.

Comment: It is a bug, it's known.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just using DeleteCases seems to work too:

```
  BeginPackage["ChurchNumerals`"];
    ZERO::usage = "ZERO is the Church encoding of zero";
    ONE::usage = "ONE is the Church numeral encoding of the integer 1";
    TWO::usage = "TWO is the Church numeral encoding of the integer 2";
    Begin["`Private`"];
    ZERO = Function[f, Function[n, n]];
    ONE = Function[f, Function[n, f[n]]];
    TWO = Function[f, Function[n, f[f[n]]]];
    End[];
    EndPackage[];
    $ContextPath = DeleteCases[$ContextPath, "ChurchNumerals`"]
```

Comment: While I appreciate the other answers, this is direct and simple and seems most like "the answer".

Answer (score 15):

There is a simpler way:

```
BeginPackage["ChurchNumerals`"];

ZERO::usage = "ZERO is the Church encoding of zero";
ONE::usage = "ONE is the Church numeral encoding of the integer 1";
TWO::usage = "TWO is the Church numeral encoding of the integer 2";

Begin["`Private`"];

ZERO = Function[f, Function[n, n]];
ONE = Function[f, Function[n, f[n]]];
TWO = Function[f, Function[n, f[f[n]]]];

End[];

Block[{$ContextPath}, EndPackage[]];
```

It is the `EndPackage` which is responsible for keeping the context on the `$ContextPath`, so you can just `Block` only it.

Note that putting a `Block` around the whole thing won't work in the `FrontEnd`, since only the top-level statements are parsed one by one in a cell - so in that case, the symbols would end up created in a wrong (`` Global` ``) context.

Comment: Any chance of fixing this sometimes annoying different behaviour of FrontEnd and Kernel parser?

Comment: @RolfMertig I think this is by design. But I am not the most knowledgable person with regard to these issues :)

Comment: I think there should not be different parsers. It is hard to figure out the difference, harder to program around them and even harder to try to teach this.

Comment: @RolfMertig I agree, there should be one parser, although parsing in the FrontEnd may need some modifications w.r.t. parsing packages still. I don't know enough of these internals to add more to this, alas.

Comment: Why does this work? I find it weird that a line like this `Block[{$ContextPath}, EndPackage[]];` can change the `$ContextPath`. Big +1 of course, I'm learning something new

Comment: @Rojo This `Block` does not *change* the `$ContextPath`, it prevents the `EndPackage` from changing it globally. It is `EndPackage` which attempts to change things here. Soon, I will run out of tricks to surprise you :-).

Comment: ...but before running that line the `$ContextPath` is just `{ChurchNumerals\`,System\`}`, and afterwards it goes back to having `Global\`` and the rest

Comment: @Rojo My guess is that `$ContextPath` is redefined by `BeginPackage`, and it is its standard function to remove from it all contexts except ``System` `` and add the package's context to it. However, the previous value is stored on some kind of stack. The way it is then restored must be something like `$ContextPath = Join[$oldContextPath,  publicly-imported-packages]`. Using `Block`, we block this modification. Then likely `EndPackage` sees `$ContextPath` as a symbolic quantity, and this prompts it to recover the previous value on the stack. Something like this.

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed, confusing. Even if it were true that you run out of tricks, [we've come a long way](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Oct/msg00766.html)

Comment: @Rojo Yeah, right. I still remember that post, for some reason, although it was nothing particularly special. I actually remember many of my posts, perhaps too many. But you've made a long way since then. You and rm -rf are among a few here who have made huge leaps in terms of Mathematica skills in an amazingly small period of time. You guys are scaring me.

Comment: Wow, good one. It's crazy that that works.

Comment: @JoelKlein Oh yeah :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin “Soon, I will run out of tricks...”—7 years past, and no, you haven't! :)

Comment: @kkm Thanks :) I wonder what prompted your comment though, since this post is pretty old.

Comment: Because it took me 7 years to discovered another amazing trick of yours that I had been unaware of. What else could? Thanks for these, really appreciated! :) Srsly, I was looking for a solution to this exact problem: avoid polluting the `Global\`` namespace with over 9000 declarations.

Comment: @kkm Glad that this helped :)

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is by taking note of how [EndPackage](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EndPackage.html) works -- by adding \$Context to \$ContextPath:

```
ChurchNumerals`Private`prevContext = Context[];
BeginPackage["ChurchNumerals`"];
  ZERO::usage = "ZERO is the Church numeral encoding of zero";
  ONE::usage = "ONE is the Church numeral encoding of the integer 1";
  TWO::usage = "TWO is the Church numeral encoding of the integer 2";
  Begin["`Private`"];
    ZERO = Function[f, Function[n, n]];
    ONE = Function[f, Function[n, f[n]]];
    TWO = Function[f, Function[n, f[f[n]]]];
  End[];
  $Context = ChurchNumerals`Private`prevContext;
EndPackage[];
```

Now the package is on `$Packages` but not `$ContextPath`, and is used qualified with the package name:

```
Map[#[Function[n, n + 1]][0] &, 
   {ChurchNumerals`ZERO, ChurchNumerals`ONE, ChurchNumerals`TWO}]
```

Comment: I would use the variable to store the context path and restore it after `EndPackage` instead of the current context. Simpler for the cases where `EndPackage` also adds the dependency list (second argument of `BeginPackage`)

Comment: Yeah, that works too. In my case I'm bending over backward *not* to introduce anything into context path, so I didn't think of that case of the 2nd argument to BeginPackage.