# How to access externally defined symbols without polluting the current namespace?

Tags: packages, scoping

**NB:** In this post, by ***fully qualified names*** I mean names like `` Global`x `` or `` SomePackage`y ``, which include their complete context information, and they are to be contrasted with ***unqualified names***, such as `x` or `ArcSin`.  Also by ***the current namespace*** I mean the set of all *unqualified* names that *Mathematica* can interpret at any given time during a session.  To *"pollute the current namespace"* means to add unwanted names to it.

---

For some time now I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to find a way to mimic in *Mathematica* Python's `import` functionality.

Specifically, in Python one can gain access to symbols implemented in external modules, *without adding those symbols to the current namespace*.

For example, suppose some function `hello` is defined in a module `foo.py`.  Then client code can access this function like this:

```
import foo
foo.hello()
```

The crucial point here is that, after `import foo`, client code **must** still use the fully qualified name `foo.hello`.  In fact, the following variant bombs:

```
import foo
hello() # fails with "NameError: name 'hello' is not defined"
```

(Of course, Python also has a mechanism to add externally defined symbols to the current namespace, but that's another matter.)

My problem with *Mathematica* is that it seems to be ***extremely hard*** to use externally defined symbols without polluting the current namespace.

AFAICT, one cannot import symbols defined within a `BeginPackage["..."]`/`EndPackage[]` pair without polluting the current namespace.  For example, if the file `foo.m` contains this:

```
(* foo.m *)

BeginPackage["foo`"];
hello[] := Print["I'm here!"];
EndPackage[];
```

...then the following client code succeeds (assuming that `foo.m` is in `$Path`):

```
Needs["foo`"];
hello[]
(* I'm here! *)
```

(The same thing happens if one uses `Get` instead of `Needs`.)

If, on the other hand, I use `Begin`/`End` instead of `BeginPackage["..."]`/`EndPackage[]`, like this:

```
(* foo.m *)

Begin["foo`"];
hello[] := Print["I'm here!"];
End[];
```

...then at least, importing this code with `Get`<sup>1</sup>, `hello` can be accessed only as `` foo`hello ``:

```
Get["/tmp/foo.m"];

hello[]
(* hello[] *)

foo`hello[]
(* I'm here! *)
```

I thought that this was the way achieve what I was after, but today I discovered that this scheme can lead to really [bewildering bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139673/2464).

---

So I'm back to square 1.

Is there some other way to import externally defined symbols without making them accessible as unqualified names?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> This doesn't work so well with `Needs`.</sup>

Comment: I have found this topic, with really neat answers. They focus more on creating process than importing but let me know, maybe it is close enough for a duplicate anywa: [**How to define a package without adding it to $ContextPath**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19028/5478)

Comment: p.s. daily tip how to find those answers, go to users - find Leonid - click - add `Block $ContextPath` to query. Done ;)

Comment: @Kuba: Thank you for helping me formulate the right question, and for your answers and comments.  I now have a lot to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to add the package with `Needs` and then remove the package context from the context path, `$ContextPath`.  An example with `` "DatabaseLink`" `` follows.

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
SQLConnections[]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

`` "DatabaseLink`" `` is loaded and its functions are available in the current context.  Remove `` "DatabaseLink`" `` from `$ContextPath`.

```
$ContextPath = $ContextPath /. "DatabaseLink`" -> Nothing;
```

Now its functions will not evaluate directly.

```
SQLConnections[]
```

> ```
> SQLConnections[]
> ```

However, if qualified with the context they do evaluate.

```
DatabaseLink`SQLConnections[]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Let me say that I do not know if this has any sort of knock-on effect in your context. I think it should be innocent enough but I would defer to more seasoned and knowledgeable members of this forum.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Write packages as always, with `BeginPackage + Begin` and in order to import them your way do what Edmund did or:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[
    {$ContextPath}
  , << GeneralUtilities`
]
```

`Block` should be enough but this is a more general in case of some fancy package setup.

```
? PrintDefinitions
```

> 

```
? GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions
```

[image]

This answers the question of how to import a package to not introduce new contexts/symbols on `$ContextPath`.

If you want to know how to write the package which will do this no matter how it is loaded then still use `BeginPackage+Begin` setup but add Edmund's fix just after `EndPackage[]`.