# Is there something wrong with VertexConnectivity

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs, version-9

**Note:** this is fixed in version 10.

---

As I noticed in the documentation `VertexConnectivity` is defined as the following

> The vertex connectivity of a graph $g$ is the smallest number of vertices whose deletion from $g$ disconnects $g$.

Now for a `CycleGraph` I expect one needs to delete at least **two vertices** to make the resulting graph disconnected. Please correct me if I am driven by a wrong intuition here.

```
opt = {VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10};
graph1 = CycleGraph[8, opt];
graph2 = UndirectedGraph[Graph[{1 -> 3, 1 -> 7, 1 -> 10, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 3 -> 6,
3 -> 10,4 -> 7, 4 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 5 -> 9, 6 -> 10, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 9}],opt];
Row[{graph1, graph2}]
```

[image]

### **Strange!**

Now Mathematica is returning this *not so intuitive* values for the `graph1` and `graph2`.

```
VertexConnectivity /@ {graph1, graph2}
```

> {1,1}

How can one make any of these above graphs disconnected by deleting just **one vertex**? Can someone shade some light on this issue? `EdgeConnectivity` though gives understandable output for both the graphs.

Comment: I think this is clearly a bug.  Can you please report it?  This would surely bite me too sooner or later.  The graph-related functions seem to have more bugs than usual.

Comment: @Szabolcs I feared the same! This type of bugs can really make the overall graph functionality very much unstable and unreliable in nature. I will wait a bit as some WRI guys are active here as well...they may comment meanwhile...

Comment: `<< Combinatorica`;
graph1 = Cycle[8, Type -> Undirected];
VertexConnectivity @graph1` always worked :D

Comment: @belisarius Unfortunately Combinatorica is not too speedy because it's implemented purely in Mathematica.

Answer (score 8):

This was confirmed by support to be a bug.

---

One workaround is to use `` Combinatorica`VertexConnectivity ``:

```
graph1 = CycleGraph[8];
graph2 = UndirectedGraph[
   Graph[{1 -> 3, 1 -> 7, 1 -> 10, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 3 -> 6, 3 -> 10, 
     4 -> 7, 4 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 5 -> 9, 6 -> 10, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 9}]];

Block[{$ContextPath},
 Needs["Combinatorica`"];
 Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
 ]

Combinatorica`VertexConnectivity@
   GraphUtilities`ToCombinatoricaGraph[#] & /@ {graph1, graph2}
```

See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5563/12) for the purpose of `Block` around `Needs`.

---

P.S. It turns out that the `` GraphUtilities`ToCombinatoricaGraph `` function re-adds Combinatorica to the context path every time it's called. If you prefer not to have Combinatorica in the context path, you can consider editing GraphUtilities.m and changing `` Needs["Combinatorica`"] `` to `` Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["Combinatorica`"]] ``.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

An easier way is using [this package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24544/12).  [Tutorial here.](http://www.nd.edu/~szhorvat/pelican/using-igraph-from-mathematica.html)

```
IGraph["vertex.connectivity"][CycleGraph[5]]

(* ==> {.2} *)
```

---

**Old version**

As a workaround, you can access igraph through RLink.  Once igraph is installed (`install.packages(igraph)`) and loaded (`library(igraph)`), do this:

```
vertexConnectivity[g_?GraphQ] := 
 Round@First@RFunction["function (e) {
        g <- graph.edgelist(e,directed=F);
        vertex.connectivity(g)
     }
     "][List @@@ EdgeList[g]]

vertexConnectivity[CycleGraph[8]]

(* ==> 2 *)
```

See also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23907/12) on how to access igraph through RLink.