# How to get a list of 3-connected graphs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, curated-data

I'd like to use `GraphData` to get a list of graphs with vertex connectivity at least 3.  I know `GraphData["Nonplanar", 6]` gives all the nonplanar graphs on 6 vertices, but I can't figure out how to get `GraphData` to do a selection based on the `"VertexConnectivity"` property.

Comment: `Select[GraphData[], (GraphData[#, "VertexConnectivity"] >= 3) &]`

Comment: What J.M. said, with the caveat that that command will initiate a loooong download.  It's good to be aware of this too: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22261/12

Comment: @J.M: Thanks.  If I'd also like to restrict by, say, "EdgeChromaticNumber" being 3, what's the best way? (I incorrectly assumed that it would be obvious to me how to generalize to more conditions.)

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks a lot for the pointer, that's good to know. I'm actually looking at 6-vertex graphs to start with (by putting `GraphData[6]` in the first part of J.M.'s command) so the download's not so bad.

Comment: @J.M.: I believe I answered my previous question (on adding more conditions), with the form e.g. `Select[GraphData[{"Nonhamiltonian", "Nonplanar", "Connected"}, 7], (GraphData[#, "EdgeChromaticNumber"] == 3 && GraphData[#, "VertexConnectivity"] >= 3) &]`. Is this correct? Would it be more efficient to somehow combine the two calls to GraphData in the condition, and is this even possible?

Comment: That looks about right to me, and I think your selection condition is as readable as it can get. Maybe you can write an answer to your own question now?

Comment: (BTW, if you want to get the "long download" Szabolcs alludes to over with, once and for all: `GraphData[All, "Preload"]`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been suggested that I combine the helpful information given in comments into an answer.  To deal with the original question (restricting the list of graphs based on `"VertexConnectivity"`), use `Select`:

```
Select[GraphData[], (GraphData[#, "VertexConnectivity"] >= 3) &]
```

However, this particular property apparently has some bugs, detailed at "[Is there something wrong with VertexConnectivity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22261/12)". To be safe, we can use the function from Combinatorica, like so.

```
Block[{$ContextPath},
 Needs["Combinatorica`"];
 Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
 ]

Select[GraphData[],
 (Combinatorica`VertexConnectivity[
     GraphUtilities`ToCombinatoricaGraph[GraphData[#]]] >= 3) &]
```

This issue did not arise for me.

To combine multiple such conditions, use `&&` between separate calls to `GraphData`, for instance:

```
Select[GraphData[], (GraphData[#, "EdgeChromaticNumber"] == 3 && GraphData[#, "VertexConnectivity"] >= 3) &]
```

All of these commands will take a *very long time.*  It helps somewhat to preload all the information, getting all the downloads over with, which you can accomplish with `GraphData[All, "Preload"]`.  But it still takes a long time to run.  Restricting to graphs of a certain size makes it much quicker.  To restrict to graphs on 7 vertices:

```
Select[GraphData[7], (GraphData[#, "EdgeChromaticNumber"] == 3 && GraphData[#, "VertexConnectivity"] >= 3) &]
```

You can also restrict this way based on the boolean properties, which `GraphData` can already do itself, as with `"Nonplanar"` in the question. Multiple ones may be combined like this:

```
Select[GraphData[{"Nonhamiltonian", "Nonplanar", "Connected"}, 7], (GraphData[#, "ChromaticNumber"] == 3) &]
```

Comment: Nicely done.$\phantom{}$