# How can I find the vertex connectivity of a random graph?

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs, graphs-and-networks, version-9

I want to know the vertex connectivity of a random graph on (say) 4 vertices.
I can get the vertex connectivity of each of the 11 graphs on 4 vertices with this:

```
Table[GraphData[{4, k}, "VertexConnectivity"], {k, 1, 11}]
```

If we label these 11 graphs we have 64 labeled graphs.  In particular, the two unlabeled graphs with connectivity 2 have 3 + 6 = 9 labelings.  I was expecting the vertex connectivity of 2 to appear with probability 9/64 in:

```
Table[VertexConnectivity[RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[4, 0.5]]], {1000}]
```

However, I do not obtain this probability form the above calculation.  I am using Mathematica 9.0.

Comment: Is this a math question or a Mathematica one?  You seem to have the answer to the question in the title.  Are you asking why you don't get 9/64?  It seems to me that you *are* getting ratios close 9/64.  So what is the question then?

Comment: If you have v9, be aware that VertexConnectivity is buggy. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22261/12

Comment: I AM using version 9.  I am NOT getting ratios that are close to 9/64.  In fact, I am not getting any 2's at all from the above code.  Are you saying version 9 does not work correctly?

Comment: See the link from my comment, the details (which I don't all remember) are in there.  All I remember is that sometimes VertexConnectivity would return incorrect answers in v9. This is fixed in v10.0+.

Comment: In version 11.0, `Count[Table[
   VertexConnectivity[
    RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[4, 0.5]]], {10000}], 
  2]/10000.` returned `0.14`.  In v9 I get 0.  v9 is definitely buggy.

Comment: OK Thanks!  I was looking for an excuse to upgrade to version 11.0 anyway :)