# Minimal Colouring of Graph Vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is there a way to colour graph vertices minimally in new *Mathematica*? I tried loading `MinimalVertexColoring` with the old *Combinatorica* package but it doesn't work and it seems to conflict with the function I'm using

```
gr = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 7, 
   1 <-> 9, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 2 <-> 7, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 
   3 <-> 9, 4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 6, 4 <-> 8, 4 <-> 9, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 7, 
   6 <-> 8, 7 <-> 8, 7 <-> 9, 8 <-> 9}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 2}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {0, 
     0}, {1, -1}, {8, 4}, {0, -2}, {-8, 4}}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]   

VertexDegree[gr]

FindHamiltonianCycle[gr, All]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has excellent graph colouring functionality, and I now recommend it over Combinatorica.

```
<< IGraphM`

Graph[gr, VertexSize -> Large] //
 IGVertexMap[ColorData[105], VertexStyle -> IGMinimumVertexColoring]
```

[image]

---

There are two problems:

1. Combinatorica is an obsolete package and many of the function/symbol names conflict with new, builtin ones.  You'll need to refer to these symbols with their fully qualified name, e.g. `` System`Graph `` and `` Combinatorica`Graph ``.  Whenever a symbol name is shown in red, you'll need to prepend a context to indicate whether you're referring to a symbol from Combinatorica of the `` System` `` context.
2. Combinatorica has been around much longer than the builtin graph datatype and has its own distinct graph representation.  You'll need to convert the graph to this format using `ToCombinatoricaGraph` from the `` GraphUtilities` `` package.

```
<< Combinatorica`
<< GraphUtilities`

gr = System`Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 
   1 <-> 7, 1 <-> 9, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 2 <-> 7, 3 <-> 4, 
   3 <-> 5, 3 <-> 9, 4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 6, 4 <-> 8, 4 <-> 9, 5 <-> 6, 
   6 <-> 7, 6 <-> 8, 7 <-> 8, 7 <-> 9, 8 <-> 9}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 2}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {0, 
     0}, {1, -1}, {8, 4}, {0, -2}, {-8, 4}}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  VertexSize -> Large]

mvc = MinimumVertexColoring@ToCombinatoricaGraph[gr]

SetProperty[gr, 
 System`VertexStyle -> 
  Thread[System`VertexList[gr] -> (ColorData[97] /@ mvc)]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Note: [This trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5574/12) is unfortunately not useful here because `` GraphUtilities`ToCombinatoricaGraph `` evaluates `` Needs["Combinatorica`"] `` each time it's evaluated, re-adding `` Combinatorica` `` to the context path.  I have suggested fixing this to WRI on multiple accounts, but so far they haven't done it.

Comment: For some reason it's not colouring the graph directly as in your answer but gives it as an ordered list of numbers from 1-4, which is still ok. Do you know of a way to randomise the colouring?