# PermutationReplace does not seem to work when Combinatorica is open. Is there a function that is equivalent.?

Tags: functions, combinatorica

I want a permutation to act on a set.  For example: I want the permutation {2,1,3,5,4} to act on the set {2,3,4} by returning {1,3,5}.  I need to do this in the same code that has functions that need Combinatorica.

I thought that maybe Orbits[pg,x] might work but I cannot understand the information in the help section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding the context of the functions explicitly if you're having clashes with *Combinatorica*, e.g. `` System`PermutationReplace[] `` and `` System`PermutationCycles[] ``:

```
System`PermutationReplace[{2, 3, 4}, System`PermutationCycles[{2, 1, 3, 5, 4}]]
```

Another possibility is suggested in Leonid's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5574):

```
Block[{$ContextPath},  Needs["Combinatorica`"]];
PermutationReplace[{2, 3, 4}, PermutationCycles[{2, 1, 3, 5, 4}]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  System`  works for me.