# A question regarding shadowed symbols

Tags: programming, packages

The more I study, the less I understand.

This is the `HelloWorld` package:

```
BeginPackage["HelloWorld`"];
helloWorld::usage="helloWorld !";
Begin["`Private`"];
helloWorld[arg_]:=arg+1;
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

This code works as obviously intended

```
(* code 1 *)
With[
{packageFile=FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"HelloWorld.m"}]},
Needs["HelloWorld`",packageFile];
];
Print @ helloWorld[1];
Quit[];
```

On the contrary, this one

```
(* code 2 *)
With[
{packageFile=FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"HelloWorld.m"}]},
Needs["HelloWorld`",packageFile];
Print @ helloWorld[1];
];
Quit[];
```

generates a message:

```
helloWorld::shdw: "Symbol ("helloWorld") appears in multiple contexts ({"HelloWorld`", "Global`"}); "
```

Now, my (bad !) reasoning is: In `(* code 1 *)`, `Needs` performs its role, at a later time the `helloWorld` symbol is "publicly visible" (from inside the `Global` context), and when the function is called there are no motives to create,   wherever, a new one named "`helloWorld`". In `(* code 2 *)`, the same should happens; all in all the `$Context` inside and outside `While[]`  is the same, as seen by

```
$Context
With[{a = 1}, Print @ $Context]
```

Quoting Mathematica's Help:

> Conflicts can occur not only between symbols in different packages,
>   but also between symbols in packages and symbols that you introduce
>   directly in your Mathematica session.If you define a symbol in your
>   current context, then this symbol may become shadowed by another
>   symbol with the same short name in packages that you read in.

The point is: in `(* code 2 *)` I haven't defined a new `helloWorld` symbol, only invoked an existing and visible one.

In [How to load a package without naming conflicts?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5563/how-to-load-a-package-without-naming-conflicts)  is explained:

> ... in this way, you don't have to do anything afterwards, since, once
>   the scope of `Block` is left, the `$ContextPath automatically is reset
>   to its previous value.

But I can't understand how this consideration 'overwrites' the above mentioned one about $Context.

Comment: This is a problem with the parsing in FrontEnd, not scoping. For the lines on the top-level, FE parses and executes them one by one, sending them as separate evaluations to the kernel. If you enclose code in some wrapper (`With`, in your case), all the code inside is parsed as a whole, and so in your second case you create a global symbol at the parsing stage, even before your package gets loaded - and so you get the shadowing. See [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917550/why-doesnt-this-use-of-begin-work) for a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply !! Do you mean that respect to a standalone kernel   `(* code 1*)` and `(* code 2 *)` work the same ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can either run the code from the FrontEnd, or inside the package, or from a text interface. In each case, the result depends on how the code is parsed and executed. I don't remember off hand the package and text-interface case, but chances are you'd get the same behavior there as well, given that `With` and everything inside it is a single expression, and so should be parsed entirely before execution. It may however be not the case if e.g. the package parser works differently. I don't have the time to test now, but it isn't hard.

Comment: I have just checked that in batch mode `(* code 1*)` and `(* code 2*)` both give `2`