# MinimumVertexColoring does not work

Tags: graphs-and-networks, color

```
 g=RandomGraph[{5,6}]
 MinimumVertexColoring[g]
```

I am using MacOS and Wolfram Mathematica 10.4

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/880870

Answer (score 2):

It is because `MinimumVertexColoring` is from the old `Combinatorica` package, and the data format of `Graph` is different from the new `Graph` in V10. To fix this problem, you will need to convert the new atomic graph object to the old representation.

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]; Needs["GraphUtilities`"];
g = System`RandomGraph[{5, 6}];
cg = ToCombinatoricaGraph[g];
MinimumVertexColoring[cg]
```

Since `RandomGraph` is in both Context, it's better to call with explicit `Context`.

Comment: ...or you can use the methods [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5563).

Comment: @J.M. Actually, no, because `ToCombinatoricaGraph` re-adds Combinatorica to the context path every time it is called.  I think the most convenient thing is to define a custom `toCombinatoricaGraph` which avoids this.

Comment: @J.M. when I executed the code, it automatically adds Combinatoria to the $ContextPath, I don't know why.

Comment: @J.M. See my comment and look at the source of `ToCombinatoricaGraph`.  It has ``Needs["Combinatorica`"]``

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks! I was wondering why this happened

Comment: @Szabolcs, tsk, that's what I get for not having *Mathematica* to try it on. Thanks.