# Loading MultivariateStatistics` changes colour of some multivariate distributions to red in notebook. Should I be worried?

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, packages, contexts

I need to use the pdf of a Wishart distribution which is only defined in the package `` MultivariateStatistics` ``. However, after loading the package, some or all of the multivariate distributions pdfs I use (e.g. `MultinormalDistribution`, `MultivariateTDistribution`) change their font colour to red.

The programme still works, but I find this strange. I've tried reading this [link on shadowing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/HandleShadowingOfSymbolNames.html) on the Wolfram site, but I'm not sure I understood it...

It means that by loading the package, now Mathematica will use the definitions from the package, and not the global definitions. Did I understand correctly? If so, I assume the definition is the same, with the possible exception of the input sintax, for example `WishartMatrixDistribution` and `WishartDistribution` have their inputs in reverse order to each other, but they should describe the same distribution...

How can I be sure that I'm using these new definitions in a proper way? Should I be worried of a possible conflict in the main programme?

I'm using version 11. At request, here's a minimal example:

```
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"]

PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, IdentityMatrix[2]], {x, y}]

(* E^(1/2 (-x^2 - y^2))/(2 π) *)
```

Comment: Can you say which version of Mathematica you are using?  Can you give a minimum example of code that you need to execute to get the problem?

Comment: @mikado I've added the information you asked for.

Comment: Hints: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoMtN.png -- but I don't have time to write an answer today...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael E2 has already hinted at what happens here. To get a deeper understanding of the issue a good place to start is the tutorial

> **[Modularity and the Naming of Things](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThingsOverview.html)**

There you will find the sections [**Contexts**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html) and [**Contexts and Packages**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ContextsAndPackages.html) that will provide most of the information needed to see why the coloring is taking place.

If you try the following, Mathematica will tell you what has happened in your case:

```
MultivariateStatistics`MultinormalDistribution
```

> **MultinormalDistribution::shdw:** Symbol MultinormalDistribution appears
>   in multiple contexts {`` MultivariateStatistics` ``, `` System` ``}; definitions in
>   context `` MultivariateStatistics` `` may shadow or be shadowed by other
>   definitions.

The symbol `MultinormalDistribution` is defined in two contexts that are both on the  `$ContextPath`.

The straight forward solution is simply to remove the superfluous symbol-definition:

```
Remove["MultivariateStatistics`MultinormalDistribution"]
```

This will only keep the definition for `MultinormalDistribution` contained in the `` System` `` context - the coloring should now be normal again.

A strategy to prevent this from the start is to prevent that `` MultivariateStatistics` `` is added to `$ContextPath` when loading a package (cf. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5563/764)):

```
Block[ {$ContextPath} , Needs["MultivariateStatistics`] ]
```

`$ContextPath` will then not contain `` MultivariateStatistics` `` and there is no shadowing. To refer to a symbol contained in the package you will have to use a full reference, e.g. `` MultivariateStatistics`MultiPoissonDistribution ``. thus, here we could probably simply remove the two symbols contained in more than one context.

Comment: Also see [**Handle Shadowing of Symbol Names**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/HandleShadowingOfSymbolNames.html).