# Graph vs. GraphPlot

Tags: graphs-and-networks

What is the difference (in purpose) between `Graph` and `GraphPlot`? Which function is bested suited to which tasks?

**Background:** I just spent the last two hours trying to make this graph readable:

```
trans = Uncompress@
   "1:eJyVV01vwjAMRfu47U/sv3RKKc2KGsahxw2YOE0aXPff17RJSZD8/HIBga3Efn5+\
dl4/f/rT32q1ujyNH+35cj09+F8v40d1/j1+XY+\
Ht8P30T2Pf9ihbyvn7Y0T3GbjzZtyM5LbYmcP9Els++FdTWJy7EwrOEYzTjbeRkHyODnvB\
adgnb7d8KHi4e3OgBudmb5sB3xsV1CBOTLpymCdv1sp/\
mBlzhq9tJrfqolRC9aSDNSzGPwxFv5f05GAldDVoJKbrgBWJsnCIuFMB/\
28JVXNMR7IQsfVvZSTCD07V79Z78Clo1VLIS+YVn5/2H67Q3h4M83wZr2B4W/\
oCmhaFDXSWysUWcVpH4sElyUTFYsEGxnPRl7nlRgTFoFBu0xGjuDToRLAs5GeeDWqes22H\
ORPLDl/FENXLXCmuVWQanrkBwmT88uGjhh8JgIyYRI91EW4aBoqtOIbg60RxD+IAGjuZC+\
QRSeXfC2qkhGor6gqD60WfdoZTOy8SGu9iONKFEJeVO7eELQGMvOD0UDYaXHN5a6DT5Zlv\
GuYlu2TmhIyD726bP5gSnswmEttWR9puG1wH6WE1VuSBI2sVNA6cfxlK6JIx7utFDE7vI5\
lyAL+Kv09FopgpA9t+\
cIcCcjZMXgYV4YWrHd86DFyR2xpTh012aCEY8sSoy3sX3A0OHUHTjWYWgR8fv/wd/kB";
Graph[DeleteDuplicates@trans, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Capsule", VertexSize -> 1, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Large, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> 
  GraphElementData["ShortUnfilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> 0.02]]
```

[image: Unreadable]

Then I discovered that `GraphPlot` produces much more readable results:

```
GraphPlot[
 DeleteDuplicates@trans /. (DirectedEdge[a_, b_] -> Rule[a, b]), 
 VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image: Readable]

which prompted me to wonder: what's the point of `Graph`?

Of course I noticed [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5254/when-to-use-built-in-graph-graphplot-vs-combinatorica), while related, which asks about the *Combinatorica* package.

Comment: `Graph` is not simply a way to plot graphs.  It is a whole new data type on which you can perform lots of operations.  It just happens to be displayed as its visualization.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all `Graph` is more recent functionality. Now try this:

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2}] // Head
```

> Graphics

and then this

```
Graph[{1 -> 2}] // Head
```

> Graph

Basically while `GraphPlot` and `GraphPlot3D` both return pure graphic objects,
`Graph` returns **true** graph which contains all information about the graph and can be computed with. For example:

```
g=Graph[{1->2}];
 AdjacencyMatrix[g] // Normal
```

> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}

Because they can be computed with, there is [wide functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphsAndNetworks.html) built around `Graph` objects which `GraphPlot` does *not* have - from graph theory to visualization and styling.

Also to get more feel for the difference you can try [`AtomQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AtomQ.html), which is the function that yields `True` if expression cannot be divided into subexpressions, and yields `False` otherwise, - as paraphrased from form Documentation Center.

```
AtomQ[g]
```

> True

Compare with

```
 AtomQ[GraphPlot[{1 -> 2}]]
```

> False

Which can be also hinted from:

```
 g // InputForm
```

> Graph[{1, 2}, {DirectedEdge[1, 2]}]

and this:

```
 GraphPlot[{1 -> 2}] // InputForm
```

> Graphics[Annotation[GraphicsComplex[{{1., 0.}, {0., 8.979318433952318*^-11}}, 
>         {{RGBColor[0.5, 0., 0.], Line[{{1, 2}}]}, {RGBColor[0, 0, 0.7], 
>           Tooltip[Point[1](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphsAndNetworks.html), 1], Tooltip[Point[2](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AtomQ.html), 2]}}, {}], 
>        VertexCoordinateRules -> {{1., 0.}, {0., 8.979318433952318*^-11}}], 
>       FrameTicks -> None, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], 
>       AspectRatio -> Automatic]

Good thing to know is that built-in [`GraphData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphData.html) return `Graph` object on default:

```
GraphData /@ GraphData["Hypotraceable"]
```

[image]

And another cool consequence of the above is that you can even copy and paste the visual representations returned by `Graph` and compute them:

[image]

Besides `GraphData` there are [many other functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphsAndNetworks.html) that return `Graph` objects, such as `CompleteGraph`, `GraphComplement`, `CayleyGraph`, `Subgraph` and so on.

Another thing to know is that `Graph` objects have their own right-click menu alowing one to deal with the graph interactively (sample workflow is shown below):

```
GraphData["IcosahedralGraph", "LineGraph"]
```

[image]

Comment: LayeredGraphPlot still often produces much better results than the equivalent Graph-based solution.  Fortunately GraphPlot does work with Graph objects---you might want to mention this!

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, thanks, I surely will add more info, - gathering it ;-) In meantime if anyone want's to see something relative added in this post - please comment.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov your answer covers what is the purpose of defining and using a graph object. But in terms of Graph visualization I see there is significant overlap between Graph and GraphPlot. The name "GraphPlot" suggests that this function specializes on plotting the graph. Perhaps another answer should highlight what are the advantages of plotting, visualizing graphs with GraphPlot, instead of Graph. And isn't it possible to merge functionality of GraphPlot into Graph ? I have also noticed that GraphPlot drawing is part of Graph Visualization.