# Create a graph from KML file

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I'm wondering how I can take a .KML (Keyhole Markup Language) file and convert/express it as a graph for use in Mathematica. Even just in general, is it possible to convert a KML file to a graph?

I'm hoping to express the US railroad system in the 19th century as a graph using this data:

http://railroads.unl.edu/resources/

Comment: You could try a [KML to CSV converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kmlcsv/). CSV can be imported in Mathematica.

Comment: Maybe this can help 
http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/04/17/mapping-gps-data/

Comment: That blog uses gpx not kml.

Comment: Well then he can do this first 
http://kml2gpx.com/

Comment: I'm sure you're aware MM supports KML as an import (and export) format. To turn an imported file into a graph (I'll assume you mean in the topological sense) you'll need to pull the appropriate attributes from the import and parse them into data that can be used with the MM graph functions. MM does not intrinsically have conversion from KML to graph format.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32478/roads-network-visualization-by-thickness-and-color-intensity-by-population-from/32498#32498) is probably related somehow since they are both GIS files, albeit with different file formats.

Answer (score 1):

using the  [KML to CSV converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kmlcsv/) converted the file South_Depots.kml from the site http://railroads.unl.edu/resources/ to CVS file.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then inside Mathematica, loaded the data and first drew on the US map

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
FileNames["*.csv"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
trainCoord = Import["South_Depots.csv"];
trainCoord = trainCoord[[All, {1, 2}]]; (*only need first 2 columns *)
trainCoord[[All, {1, 2}]] = trainCoord[[All, {2, 1}]]; (*swap coordinates*)
trainCoordGeo = Map[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], "Mercator"][[1]] &, 
    {trainCoord}, {2}][[1]];  (*make it GEO*)

UScoords = CountryData["UnitedStates", "Coordinates"];
UScoordsGeo = Map[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], "Mercator"][[1]] &, 
  {UScoords}, {2}][[1]]; (*make it GEO*)


 Graphics[
 {
  {Gray, Polygon[UScoordsGeo]},
  {Red, PointSize[.005], Point[trainCoordGeo]}
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To convert the data to Mathematica graph data, one way is

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
trainCoord = Import["South_Depots.csv"];
trainCoord = trainCoord[[All, {1, 2}]];
Needs["GraphUtilities`"];
g = Rule @@@ trainCoord[[1 ;; 20]];
coords = GraphCoordinates[g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

now that you have the CVS data, you can do any other graph operations you want on it inside Mathematica.

reference :  [how-do-i-plot-coordinates-latitude-and-longitude-pairs-on-a-geographic-map](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/how-do-i-plot-coordinates-latitude-and-longitude-pairs-on-a-geographic-map)

**Update**: I just saw Rasher comment above that M supports reading KML. Yes, I just tried it

```
   trainCoord = Import["South_Depots.kml"];
```

This can be another option to read the data. It seems to be graphic data.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: By default it returns graphics, yes, but take a look at `Import["file","Elements"]` and specifically `Import["file","Data"]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've successfully repeated your steps. My problem now is that the vertices don't have edges connecting them. But why would they? I've only given the graph unconnected points, correct?

Comment: @RobertMogel: KML are not obligated to have paths (routes). If they don't, you're probably out of luck, unless you have some other data to associate points to paths.