# How to make Layer Directed Graphs (LDG) in mathematica?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am wondering if I can make a graph like that somehow: [image: LDG Graph for a Chemical Process Industry]

I am new to mathematica, I tried to play with [Creating a graph with variable size of vertices and variable thickness of edges](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6440/creating-a-graph-with-variable-size-of-vertices-and-variable-thickness-of-edges/6450#6450) . I figured if I could get the data in that form I could make some changes and try to adapt it to mine. But that is not working.

Can someone help me please??

This is what the data sample looks like in tabulated form: [image]

I used this:

```
trans = Uncompress@
"1:eJxTTMoPShNkYGAoZgESPpnFJWlMIB4PkHDJLEpNLklNcU1JTy1mBEkXg+\
TcDAkrMcKjJASsJASXKWBJI4hKPErcIEp8BolzIdRAuxdqEUE/Uc0mfF5CdowhABdjfqo=\
 ";
l = VertexList[Graph[trans]];
(*Weigths for vertices*)
r = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, Length[l]];
vs = Transpose@{l, r} /. List[a_, b_] -> Rule[a, b];
(*Adjust font size*)
vls = Transpose@{l, r} /. 
List[a_, b_] -> Rule[a, Directive[Black, Bold, 20*b]];
(*Weigths for line thicknes*)
rr = RandomReal[{0.1, 1}, Length[DeleteDuplicates@trans]]/100;
es = (First@# > Directive[Thickness[Last@#], Opacity[.5]]) & /@ 
Transpose@{DeleteDuplicates@trans, rr};
g = Graph[DeleteDuplicates@trans, 
VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
VertexShapeFunction -> "Capsule", VertexSize -> vs, 
VertexLabelStyle -> vls, EdgeStyle -> es, 
EdgeShapeFunction -> 
GraphElementData["ShortUnfilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> 0.03]]
```

and got this, which is not what I need
[image: Graph]

Comment: @Kuba I made the edit to include the data set.

Comment: try to put DeleteDuplicate when you generate the first graph: l = VertexList[Graph[DeleteDuplicates@trans]]

Comment: @halmir I actually need to find a way to assign the data to different planes of the graph with a keyword like M,L,R,N & AWA. See figure 1? Its not duplicate data, its data for different planes.

Comment: @Kuba have a look at the data now please?

Comment: @MariaIftikhar I can't help you, I'm not experienced enought in graphs. Take a look at `GraphPlot3D` it may be useful.