# Density plot of city data

Tags: graphics

I try to solve a bit tricky problem. I want define line (or vector) between some geographical points with weights (for example how many transactions has been done between these cities).

I tried this way:

```
c1 = CityData["Paris", "Coordinates"] ;
c2 = CityData["London", "Coordinates"];
c3 = CityData["Hong Kong", "Coordinates"];

ListDensityPlot[{{c1, c2, 5}, {c2, c3, 1}}]
```

Where 5 and 1 in ListDensityPlot are weights.

When I evaluate this code I always get error message. Is it possible to make this simalution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is `ListDensityPlot` *really* what you mean to use?  It sounds nothing like the description "I want define line (or vector) between some geographical points with weights."  Have you looked at `Graph`?  Is this something like what you want?: [(6440)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6440)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your link looks like what I need. But when we use GeoGraphics it would be also possible to use density, isn't it? Check my comment bellow (we have x as well as y coordinates and z is density).

Answer (score 7):

EDITED to add Tooltips

```
loc1 = "Paris";
loc2 = "London";
loc3 = "Hong Kong";

{c1, c2, c3} = CityData[#, "Coordinates"] & /@ 
  {loc1, loc2, loc3};

GeoGraphics[{
  Red, AbsoluteThickness[5],
  Tooltip[GeoPath[{c1, c2}],
   loc1 <> " - " <> loc2 <> ": " <> ToString[GeoDistance[c1, c2]]],
  Blue, AbsoluteThickness[1],
  Tooltip[GeoPath[{c2, c3}],
   loc2 <> " - " <> loc3 <> ": " <> ToString[GeoDistance[c2, c3]]]},
 GeoRange -> {{20, 60}, {-10, 120}},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: It looks great. But is it possible to add there also density or something like 3D graph? It is maybe stupid but I think we have x as well as y coordinates and z is density. In this case it doesn't matter but when we have many lines it would be more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

some ideas using `TreePlot`

```
TreePlot[{{1 -> 2, 50}, {3 -> 1, 70}, {2 -> 3, 100}} /. {1 -> "Paris",
    2 -> "London", 3 -> "Hong Kong"}, VertexLabeling -> True]


(* sophisticated version *)
vertexLabel[city_] := 
 city <> "\n" <> ToString@CityData[city, "Coordinates"]
TreePlot[{{1 -> 2, 50}, {3 -> 1, 70}, {2 -> 3, 100}} /. {1 -> 
    vertexLabel@"Paris", 2 -> vertexLabel@"London", 
   3 -> vertexLabel@"Hong Kong"}, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: cityDataPlot]