# Offset directed edge arrows with VertexLabels in panels

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling, visualization

This Q is related to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144788/graph-styling-offset-directed-edge-arrows-when-vertex-sizes-are-different) but haven't found a way to extend it to the use of `VertexLabels` in panels.

Given this graph data:

```
CCIFigure = { {"CCI Groups Dictionary", {0, 1}, 
     a}, {"Computational CCI Groups", {0, 1/2}, 
     b}, {"Scraped VASD Text/Codes", {-1, 0}, 
     a}, {"Extracted UCSD Codes", {1, 0}, 
     a}, {"Normalized ICD9", {0, 0}, b}} // associationIndex //    Dataset
```

This graph has combinations of directed and undirected edges:

```
Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
  3 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 5},
 VertexCoordinates -> Normal@Normal[CCIFigure [All, 2]],
 VertexLabels -> Normal@Normal[CCIFigure [All, 1]]]
```

[image]

However, using `VertexLabels` in panels as per reference pages:

```
Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
  3 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 5},
 VertexCoordinates -> Normal@Normal[CCIFigure [All, 2]],
 VertexLabels -> 
  Normal@Normal[CCIFigure [All, 1 /*  (Placed[#, Center, panel] &)]]]
```

results in arrowheads occluded by the panel:

[image]

Is there some combination of options or workaround to fix without knowing in advance the length of the text or panel margins?

Graph layout would have to be aware of bounding box, but from WTC2017 there doesn't seem to be a user-friendly solution to this.

helper functions:

```
panel[lbl_] := 
 Panel[lbl, FrameMargins -> 0, Background -> Lighter[Yellow, 0.7]]
```

and

```
associationIndex[l_List]:=Query[MapIndexed[First[#2]->#1&]/*Association][l]
```

Comment: Did you already try using `Placed[#, {After, Above}, panel] &`?

Comment: @J.M., I see `{After,Above}` puts panels besides the vertices which are rendered as circles - it's an option I will consider but it's not as clean as the panels themselves as the vertices.

Answer (score 2):

```
f = Normal @ Normal[CCIFigure[All, 1 /* panel]] /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[a, Inset[b, #]&];

Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 <-> 5,  3 -> 5, 4 -> 5}, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> f, 
 VertexCoordinates -> Normal @ Normal[CCIFigure [All, 2]], 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

As @Szabolcs noted in a comment:

> The key points here are:
>    1.  use `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` to auto-offset the arrows
>    2.  the offsetting is done for the vertex shape, not the vertex label.

**Update:** A more cumbersome alternative is using `VertexSize`:

```
g = Graph[ {1 -> 2, 2 <-> 5, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 5}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> Normal@Normal[CCIFigure [All, 2]],
  VertexLabels -> Normal@Normal[CCIFigure [All, 1 /*  (Placed[#, Center, panel] &)]], 
  ImageSize -> {600, 400}]
```

[image]

```
labelsizes = Normal[Values[ImageDimensions /@ Rasterize /@ panel /@ CCIFigure[[All, 1]]]];
vsizes = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, 
   ImageScaled /@ N@Transpose[Transpose[labelsizes]/ImageDimensions[Image@g]]];
SetProperty[g, {VertexShapeFunction -> None, VertexSize -> vsizes, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImagePadding -> 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but in an era of Siri and "deep learning" why do we have to manually do all this?

Comment: @alan, we won't have to in version 11.4 i hope:)

Comment: @kglr Do you know anything about 11.4?

Comment: @alancalvitti The key points here are: 1. use `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` to auto-offset the arrows 2. the offsetting is done for the vertex shape, not the vertex *label*. Originally you simply overlaid labels that were larger than the vertices.

Comment: @Szabolcs, `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` doesn't work on my original code, only in kglr's method.

Comment: @alancalvitti I addressed that in point 2: offsetting is done for the vertex *shape*, not the *label*. You just added labels.

Comment: @Szabolcs, re v11.4, just know my wish list:). Re the key points in you comment, if you are not going to post an answer, can I add them to my post?

Comment: Of course, feel free to add them.