# Drawing a GraphPlot by preserving the structure of the graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

For eg.
`GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 4}, VertexLabeling -> True]`
 
[image: original graph]

Then If I remove the edge (say `1->4`) and redraw the graphplot then I have
[image: second graph]

One can see the structure is not preserved. I want that looks like the same as the first one but without the edge `1->4`. i.e., with vertices same at the coordinates as the previous one

My second question:
I noticed that if I have a huge graph drawn with the option of `Graph` not `GraphPlot` I am not able to resize the vertices. How can I resize them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a `GraphPlot`, then it is simply a `Graphics` object, and you can't do any of the interactive things you can do with a `Graph`.  Look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6411/9490) for info on the differences between the two functions.

If you want the vertices for the second `GraphPlot` to have the same coordinates as the first, then you need to specify the `VertexCoordinateRules`.  To do this, you need a list of coordinates, which you can get from a `Graph`, but not from a `GraphPlot`.  So first you have to create a graph from the edge rules, extract the coordinates via the `GraphEmbedding` function, and feed those back into either `Graph` or `GraphPlot`.

```
edgelist = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 4};
With[{g = Graph[edgelist]},
 {
  GraphPlot[
   DeleteCases[edgelist, 4 -> 1],
   VertexLabeling -> True, 
   VertexCoordinateRules -> 
    Thread[VertexList[g] -> GraphEmbedding[g]]],
  Graph[
   DeleteCases[edgelist, 4 -> 1],
   VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   VertexCoordinates -> Thread[VertexList[g] -> GraphEmbedding[g]]]
  }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Only in the `Graph` can you resize the vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Jason probably has answer you need but I choose to take a blindingly simple interpretation of the question, and offer:

```
GraphPlot[
  {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 4}
  , VertexLabeling -> True
] /. {4, 1} -> Sequence[]
```

[image]

For the second question you should be able to use either [`VertexRenderingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexRenderingFunction.html) or [`VertexSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexSize.html), for `GraphPlot` and `Graph` respectively.  Give a specific example of what you need and I'll try to provide a solution.