# Intelligent edges with fixed vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Take for instance the simple graph

```
Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3},
VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}}, 
VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image: graph1]

and note that the edges `1<->3` and `2<->3` overlap visually. Is there a way to keep the manual vertex positioning and have the edges reroute intelligently?

Another, more interesting, example where overlapping edges really start to become a problem:

```
g = Graph[Range[9], 
EdgeList@AdjacencyGraph[
ConstantArray[1, {9, 9}] - IdentityMatrix[9]], 
VertexCoordinates -> Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}], 1], 
VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image: graph2]

---

For `GraphPlot` there is an option `MultiedgeStyle` that controls spacing between edges.

```
GraphPlot[g, MultiedgeStyle -> #] & /@ {0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1}
```

[image: graph3]

Especially for stuff like `HighlightGraph` and `EdgeStyle` to selectively stylize edges I'd rather keep using `Graph` instead of `GraphPlot` and friends. See this [Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6411/graph-vs-graphplot) for more details about the differences between the two.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork My question is wether/how one can make a graph's visual representation smarter with regard to overlapping edges.

Answer (score 3):

You could try "CurvedArc" EdgeShapeFunction:

```
Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}}, 
 VertexLabels -> Automatic, EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc"]

Graph[Range[9], 
 EdgeList@AdjacencyGraph[
   ConstantArray[1, {9, 9}] - IdentityMatrix[9]], 
 VertexCoordinates -> Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}], 1],
  VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> 
  GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> .3}]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you tell me how you found out about `"CurvedArc"`? The documentation states that `GraphElementData["EdgeShapeFunction"]` can be used to find all `EdgeShapeFunction`s but `CurvedArc` is not listed among them for me.

Comment: Using `"Curvature" :> RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}]` produces nice results if one does not wish the graph to uniformly "slant" in one specific direction.